# How can I exclude the shown node without reducing the row count?

Tags: views

I have a view block for related content in which I've configured a contextual filter ("Content ID from URL") such that, when displaying the block on a node, that node node is excluded from the view. However, in cases where the current node is captured in the view, the total row count is reduced (in my case, from 3 rows to 2 rows) per the exclusion. In other words, the filter doesn't simply filter out node when making the query, it removes the node from the query result (so far as I understand the process).

Is there a way to configure the view so that excluding the current node does not reduce the overall row count? I tried ordering the the contextual filters so that that the node exclusion occurs first, but this doesn't have any effect on the result.

Comment: Well do you want the current node in the results or not? It seems you aren't talking about count of results (as a reported number) but the actual number or rows in the list. If you only want to report the number of total results you could use Attachment Display without the Contextual and it will show the total count, Attach it to the Block.

Comment: Excluding a node ID from results shouldn't necessarily reduce the total row count. I.e. your understanding above seems incorrect based on my experience. Can share how you're excluding the node? Is it possible that there are only 3 possible results (including the current node) and that's why it's reduced from 3 to 2?

Comment: After playing around with the configuration, it seems I'm encountering a separate issue wherein trying to accommodate for multiple taxonomy vocabularies throws off what I would expect for the results. Thanks for your feedback.